# Retrieve defects associated with test set using REST API in ALM

Tags: api, hp-alm

Below REST API gives all the defects under project from ALM

```
/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/defects/
```

Is there any way to get the linked defects associated with test set in ALM using REST API?

Answer (score 0):

following query will help if HPALM version is >= 11.5

```
/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/defect-links?query={second-endpoint-id[test-set-id];second-endpoint-type[test-set]}"
```

Thx
Gaurav